# Confusion between use of `|` to combine two dictionaries vs in match-case

Tags: python, pattern-matching, structural-pattern-matching

we know that `|` is used to combine two dictionaries,
like,

```
dct_1 = {'a': 1}
dct_2 = {'b': 2}
print(dct_1 | dct_2)
```

gives,

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

but if one wants to use the same `|` in match-case to combine two dictionaries,

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d = {'a': 1}
c = {'b': 2}
match x:
  case d | c: print(x)
```

gives error,

```
SyntaxError: name capture 'd' makes remaining patterns unreachable
```

as they have made `|` equivalent to or in match-case.
similarly,

```
match x:
  case ({**d} | {**c}): print(x)
```

gives,

```
SyntaxError: alternative patterns bind different names
```

similarly,

```
match x:
  case (d | {**c}): print(x)
```

gives,

```
SyntaxError: alternative patterns bind different names
```

and,

```
match x:
  case ({**d} | c): print(x)
```

gives,

```
SyntaxError: alternative patterns bind different names
```

how do I use `|` to combine two dictionaries in a case statement?

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be when you combine dictionaries in `case`? Are you sure it even makes sense?

Comment: that ‘|’ works like it does to combine two dictionaries, and we get ‘x’ matches with the combined dictionary

Comment: But the case argument is a pattern, not a value. What is the pattern you're trying to match when you combine two dictionaries?

Comment: Any dictionary which contains ‘{‘a’: 1, ‘b’: 2}’ should match with ‘case d | c’. a dictionary like {‘a’: 1, ‘b’: 2, ‘e’: 1} should match.

Comment: What if there are conflicting keys in the two dictionaries?

Comment: what does conflicting keys mean, I do not know, does it mean like this, `x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'a': 5}`. the documentation says something like this, `If duplicate keys are detected in the mapping pattern, the pattern is considered invalid. A SyntaxError is raised for duplicate literal values; or a ValueError for named keys of the same value.`

Comment: I mean `x = {'a': 1, 'b: 2'} y = {'a': 3}`

Comment: I expect the `|` to work as it does for standard dictionaries, in the above scenario, `x | y` would give `{'a': 3, 'b': 2}`, and `case x | y` should match with any dictionary containing `{'a': 3, 'b': 2}` but instead it raises error as I described in the post.

Comment: All other uses of `|` in cases means "or", so doing it differently for dictionaries would be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that the `case` statement does not care about the assignments,

```
dct_1 = {'a': 1}
dct_2 = {'b': 2}
```

if we do,

```
dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dct_1 = {'a': 1}
dct_2 = {'b': 2}
match dct:
  case {'a': 1} | {'b': 2}: 
    print("using {'a': 1} | {'b': 2}", dct)
```

then it outputs,

```
using {'a': 1} | {'b': 2} {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

so, probably there is nothing wrong with the use of `|` for dictionaries.

similar situation could be seen here,

```
dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
eee = '1'
match dct:
  case eee: print("using eee", dct)
```

which outputs,

```
using eee {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

here, again `case` does not care about the assignment,

```
eee = '1'
```

and,

```
case eee:
```

is more like a wildcard pattern matching

if I do something like this, (using `'1'` instead of `eee` in `case` statement)

```
dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
eee = '1'
match dct:
  case '1': print("using '1'", dct)
```

then it would attempt at matching the dictionary `dct` with `'1'` and it fails (as expected), so, there is no output.

Comment: The logic is not "does not care about the assignments".  The logic is "creates a local variable to hold the matched result" instead.  If you write your example as `case eee: print(eee)` you will see `eee` is created here to hold the matched `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`.  As you mentioned "a wildcard pattern matching".  Yes, it is.

Comment: The we can come to a conclusion that patterns are literally composed by constants, and cannot be passed in from outer variables, because any variables inside patterns are treated as result-holding variables.